# i have 3 views (say 3 worksheets) iterating through a folder,i need to make single workbook

Tags: python, tableau-api, read.csv, tableau-desktop

My Code :

```
path="C:/MasterData?"
for view in Workbook.views:
 server.views.populate_csv(view)
 with.open(path+'Output.xlsx','wb') as f:
  f.write(b''.join(view.csv)
```

In Tableau,I am iterating each worksheets in dasboard.I am generatng csv view and save it as excel file.Is there any possible i can create single workbook with 3 seperate sheeets(iterate through each view)

Answer (score 0):

Possible:

Method 1:Use XML structure
1)If Organisation policy doesnt allow you to install aditional library.
Built our own python Excel using using XmL and save it as xls format.
2)Incase your allowed to use library named "Excelwriter","openpyxl" that will be more helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).